# Little/Big Endian shifting position

Tags: c, bit-shift, riscv

I have written some code, that stores an integer from a char array[2304]

Into an integer array,essentially, if my character array has the integer 1000, it is stored across 4 bytes

memory_array[0]= first byte of 1000;

memory_array[1] = second byte of 1000;

memory_array[2] = third byte of 1000;

memory_array[3] = final byte of 1000;

I have a function called read_int that takes an index (where the first byte of the value is stored)

And returns an integer collating all the other 3 bytes to form the value 1000

Now, my friend asked me a question,

"You’ll have to consider the endian system you’re using. If it’s small endian then you’ll need to shift the position of each byte"

I am unsure what he means by this, how would I go about shifting the position  of each byte in my implementation below, and how do I know what endian system I am using

My store int stores a integer into my char* array spreading it across 4 spaces for each byte.

```
  void load(unsigned char* instruction){
   int rd = get_register_to_store_into(instruction,21,25);
   int virtual_rountine_access =
           registers[get_register_to_store_into(instruction,13,17)]
           + extract_typeI_imm(instruction);
   int value = 0;

       registers[rd] = read_int(blob.memory,
                                            virtual_rountine_access);
}
```

Here is my code for how i store and retrieve from array

```
  void store_int(unsigned char* arr, int index, int value) {
    arr[index] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+3] = value & 0xFF;
}

int read_int(const unsigned char* arr, int index) {
    int value = 0;
    value |= ((int)arr[index]) << 24;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+1]) << 16;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+2]) << 8;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+3]);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Your code already takes care of the endianess by always storing the MSB first and the LSB last. It'll store it the same independently of what endian the machine uses. The only problem I can think of is if you use something else than the `store_int` and `read_int` functions to actually store or read `int`s. Also, you should probably not assume `sizeof(int) == 4`.